# Solr edismax SearchHandler clarification

Tags: search, solr, edismax

I am using edismax SearchHandler in my search and I have some issues in the search results. As I understand if the "defaultOperator" is set to OR the search query will be passed as  -> The OR quick OR brown OR fox implicitly. However if I search for The quick brown fox, I get lesser results than explicitly adding the OR. Another issue is that if I search for The quick brown fox other documents that contain the word fox is not in the search results.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want an OR search using edismax you should set the mm (must match) parameter to 1. Not 100% sure if/how the defaultOperator works using edismax qparser. according to  http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Default_query_parser_operator     "It is preferable to not use or rely on this setting; instead the request handler or query LocalParams should specify the default operator. This setting here can be omitted and it is being considered for deprecation."

Answer (score 0):

Make sure mm is 0%. Then the search should be OR.